Cannot model front headlight housing
I am a beginner in 3D modeling, and I need help creating the shape of a part. Currently, I am trying to model a 2012 Pagani Huayra car, but I am facing some difficulties. I am struggling to create the housing for the front headlights. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me with this part and explain how to make it.
